# MongoDB set user as admin of selected databases

Tags: mongodb, authentication, roles

I need to create user in MongoDB with "root" role but only to few selected databases (database_one and database_two).
An my questions are:

1. In which database should I create user?
2. Do I need to create custom roles? With what settings?
3. Which roles should I grant to user?

My plan was that I create user in DB admin, set roles dbAdmin, userAdmin, readWrite with both databases (database_one and database_two). But in this case I'm not able to connect as this user.
Can you help me how to setup user and his roles?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have chosen a current database (by using this command `use <databaseName>`) that you are already working with, then you can try below code to add a user and specify his/her credentials and roles.

```
db.addUser({user: "root", pwd: "123456", roles: [ "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "clusterAdmin" ]}));
```

OR to create a user admin for a single database:

```
use <databaseName>
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "recordsUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdmin", db: "records" } ]
  }
)
```

More from [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-administrator/)

Comment: When I use your example #1, created user has access to all databases. But user has to have access only to 2 specified databases. And when I use your second example, I have to create same user twice in both databases. But this solution is not effective for me, because each time I want to change user password, I have to change them in both DBs.